# How to get a callback of when a tkinter text widget is changed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a callback function that is gonna run when a text widget is modified. I've looked all over the internet and only came across how people did so with entry widgets and `StringVar`. I've also found out that a text widget doesn't have a `textvariable` attribute, so I can't use `StringVar` with it. So how can I can I detect when a text widget is modified?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer to this shortly after I posted this question, so I thought I'd post an answer to help other people who encounter this problem. My solution:

```
from tkinter import *


def get_stringvar(event):
    sv.set(text1.get("1.0", END))
    text2.replace("1.0", END, sv.get())


root = Tk()

sv = StringVar()

text1 = Text(root)
text1.pack()
text1.bind('<KeyRelease>', get_stringvar)


text2 = Text(root)
text2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I basically bound the first text widget to the `get_stringvar` function and updated the `StringVar` in that function. Then, I displayed the first text widget's input in the second text widget

Comment: A use of `StringVar` here is not so important, you can use a variable instead too

Comment: If you're trying to mirror the contents of one text widget in another, the text widget has a built-in feature for that. Is that the reason you're asking this question?

Comment: @BryanOakley, no I'm actually working on an html editor, but I didn't want to add code that's too long to my question. I need to get a callback of when a text widget is modified so I can autocomplete html elements. For example, if the user types <h1>, the script will immediately add </h1> after it